# Install php8.1 modules/extensions on debian11 (bullseye) php8.1 image

Tags: php, docker, debian, php-8.1

I've got a debian image for php, `php:fpm-bullseye` and it runs fine. The issue is that I want to add more php packages to this image, so according to instructions online, the steps are

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install -y lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common gnupg2`
3. `echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sury-php.list`
4. `wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
5. `sudo apt update`
6. `sudo apt install php8.1-<extension>`

Everything works fine until I get to step 6. If i run `php -v` it shows me

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 28 2022 08:17:49) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

So it's not like PHP isn't installed at all, but it will not find *any* of the extensions for php. I've run through this several times and I don't see what I am missing.

What is the proper way to install php packages on debian?

Comment: Do you see the extensions available when you run a search? `apt search php` You may also need to run `apt upgrade`

Comment: Extensions can be seen with this `php -r "print_r(implode(', ', get_loaded_extensions()));"`

Comment: Actually you want to run `php -i`, do you?

Comment: @MarshallC when I run it, I see `php8.1-common/bullseye 8.1.6-1+0~20220517.17+debian11~1.gbp6b3bd1 amd64`

Comment: @MarshallC and `apt search php | grep 8.1 | grep common` was the command I had run, since I wanted to install `php8.1-common`

Comment: oh.. I need to add `/bullseye` to the end of my install command I think

Comment: @MarshallC please write your comment as the answer and I will accept it. What I was missing was having a good way of searching apt repos for available packages. I had tried to search for that as well but had a hard time finding a concise command like you wrote. Thank you for the quick answer!